# How can I generate 3 different (unique) numbers in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, numbers, unique

a question from a beginner.
So I've used

```js
let myArray = [];

function randomNumbers(){
  for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    if(Math.floor(Math.random()*10) !== myArray[i]){
      myArray.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*10));
    }
  }
}

randomNumbers()
console.log(myArray)
```

Code above gives me 3 random number as intended but sometimes it's giving me same number twice and in very rare occasion, same number 3 times.

Comment: You can create your array with numbers 0 to 9, then shuffle that array, and grab the first 3 numbers from that array

Answer (score 2):

When generating random numbers, there is always the chance of getting duplicates. However as you specifically require 3 random numbers, I'd suggest checking that each number you generate does not already exist in the array of numbers.

I can see you have somewhat attempted to ensure that the same number isn't added twice in a row, however as you call `Math.random()` twice, once in the `if` and once when you `push` the number, you will actually be generating a new number each time.

Try instead using `.includes()` to check if the number already exists in the array.

Something like this:

```js
let myArray = [];

function randomNumbers() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    while (!myArray[i]) {
      let newRandomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
      if (!myArray.includes(newRandomInt)) {
        myArray.push(newRandomInt)
      }
    }
  }
}

randomNumbers()
console.log(myArray)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response! Will have a check at .includes() :)

Comment: I wouldn't bother with the for...loop. Just have `while` check `myArray.length`.

Comment: @Andy tried and it works! Thanks for the help guys, I always had this idea that for loop is just always better than while or do while loop but I guess not

Comment: @Andy good point, thanks I'll update my solution

Answer (score 0):

here is array generate numbers without repeatition [demo](https://js-demo.com/index.php?ref=f6530de92d2d)

Comment: Thanks for your response, the code you've shown me seems nice but it's gonna take me some time to understand. Have a good day!

Comment: @AabB - Welcome to Stack Overflow, when answering questions it's often good to explain your answer to be of most benefit to the OP and future readers (code comments that you've added are good though). Stack Overflow also allows you to embed runnable snippets into your answer, without having to take readers off-site to view parts of your answer. Here is how you can make one: [I've been told to create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets", how do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992)

Comment: Okay but it has no library